# useless match=text() in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

when an exerice asks me to copy text from input to output, I often put this code:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

But I noticed that almost always it's useless. Is there any case in which I MUST use this code, or it's always useless?

For example, in this case the output is the same with or without those three lines of code:
INPUT:

```
<z>
    <d>testo 0
        <rad>testo 1</rad>
    </d>
    <b>
        <p>
            <w>
                <z>testo 2</z>
            </w>
        </p>
    </b>
    <d>
        <p/>
        <y>testo 3
            <d>testo 4</d>
        </y>
        <p>testo 5
            <d>testo 6</d>
        </p>
        <p/>
    </d>
    <z/>
</z>
```

Desired output:

```
<z>
<nuovo livelloInput="figlio radice">testo 0
<rad livelloInput="nipote radice">testo 1</rad>
</nuovo>
<nuovo livelloInput="figlio radice">
<p livelloInput="nipote radice">testo 2</p>
</nuovo>
<nuovo livelloInput="figlio radice">
<p livelloInput="nipote radice"/>
<y livelloInput="nipote radice">testo 3 testo 4</y>
<p livelloInput="nipote radice">testo 5 testo 6</p>
<p livelloInput="nipote radice"/>
</nuovo>
<nuovo livelloInput="figlio radice"/>
</z>
```

XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <nuovo>
            <xsl:attribute name="livelloinput">figlioradice</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        </nuovo>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:attribute name="livelloInput">nipoteradice</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default behavior for text nodes, due to the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). So you don't absolutely need that template.